# probability that the correct size T-shirt can be searched in $8th$ attempt

Tags: probability

### Questions

I found this question [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-mock-2018-set-2-question-51/) but i was thinking to solve it other way.

> In a bunch of $13$ T-shirts only one is of Medium size, which is correct fit for the searching person. Each time wrong size is picked, the person throws it away and pick the next T-shirt. What is the probability that the correct size T-shirt can be searched in $8th$ attempt ?

### My Approach

Can't i use property of complement,

Initially the probability of picking correct, $p=\frac{1}{13}$

so not picking correct initially $=\frac{12}{13}$
moving on till $8^{th}$ attempt,
$$\frac{12}{13} \times \frac{11}{12} \times \frac{10}{11} \times \frac{9}{10} \times \frac{8}{9} \times...\times \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{6} $$

Am i going right?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement and solution on that website are both atrocious. The problem is not written in standard English: no speaker of standard English would say "can be searched in 8th attempt." (There are multiple errors in that phrase.)

To fix this, we can keep the word "in" and fix the language around it:
"can be *found* in 8 *attempts,*"
meaning we have a successful outcome if any of the first eight shirts that are selected is the medium shirt.
Alternatively, we can keep the words "8th attempt" and fix the language before them:
"*will* be *found on the* 8th attempt,"
meaning we have a successful outcome if eight shirts are selected and the eighth one is the medium shirt.

The simple solution is that in either interpretation, that probability that the "successful event" occurs is unchanged if we continue selecting shirts until all have been selected.
That is, the selection process puts the shirts into a random order,
and we have a "success" if the shirt is in any of the first eight positions
(first interpretation) or in the eighth position (second interpretation).

Assuming each remaining shirt is equally likely to be chosen at each step,
the random order produced by selecting all shirts one after the other
is equally distributed over all permutations of the shirts,
and a specific shirt (in this case the medium one) is equally likely to end up in any of the positions in the sequence.
Since there are $13$ shirts in the sequence, the probability to be in any of the first eight positions is $\frac{8}{13},$
and the probability to be in the eighth position is $\frac{1}{13}.$

The proposed solution on the website makes the absurd claim that the probability *not* to find a medium shirt on the first attempt is
$\frac{8}{13}.$ That would be the correct probability if the problem statement said there were five medium shirts, but the problem statement clearly says there is only one.
Hence the correct probability is $\frac{12}{13}.$
The remaining probabilities are as written in the question above.
That is, you have partially solved the problem 
(under the assumption that "success" means finding the medium shirt only on the eighth attempt, not earlier)
by directly computing
$P(L'_1 \cap L'_2 \cap L'_3 \cap L'_4 \cap L'_5 \cap L'_6 \cap L'_7 \cap L_8),$
as proposed on the web site,
with the difference between your answer and the one on the web site
being attributable to the fact that you computed the probabilities
correctly and they gave the wrong probabilities.
You need only make the obvious cancellations
in order to obtain a simple fraction.